# How to change multiple char in string in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, string, char

i want to replace string like :

CD7849O => CD18490

so if you find a char in the form of 7 and O, replace them with 1 and 0 (7 => 1, O => 0)

i tried with indexofchar but it's not work

```
string result = "CD7849O";

string[] charToFind = { "0", "O", "I", "1", "7" };
foreach (string z in charToFind)
{
    string charFind = z;
    int indexOfChar = result.Trim().IndexOf(charFind);
    Console.WriteLine(indexOfChar);

    if (indexOfChar >= 0)
    {
        string y = "XXX";
        string x = "XXX";

       
        if (z == "0" && z == "1")
        {
            y = "O";
            x = "I";
        }
        else if (z == "O" && z == "I")
        {
            y = "0";
            x = "1";
        }
        else if (z == "O" && z == "7")
        {
            y = "0";
            x = "1";
        }

        string resultY = result.Trim().Replace(charFind, y);
        string resultHasil;
        Console.WriteLine(resultY);
    }
}
```

Comment: read up on [String.Replace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-7.0)

Comment: how do i find char 7 and O then replace with char 1 and 0

Comment: @KikiOlivia `Replace` finds all instances of `char` in string and produces a new one with the replaced characters.

Comment: @KikiOlivia what is your goal and what is not working in the provided code?

Answer (score 1):

Use String.Replace()

```
string result = "CD7849O";
// replace 7 -> 1
result = result.Replace("7", "1");
// replace O -> 0
result = result.Replace("O", "0");
```

Comment: how do i find char 7 and O in string result ?, i know how to replace but I want to find if there are '7' and 'O'  replace of '1' and '0'

Comment: @KikiOlivia, why are you specifying a requirement in a comment on an answer that you didn't specify in the question? Why would you think that it's a good idea to only provide half the relevant information in the question? Provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation in the question. That should be a given.

Comment: OP already uses `Replace`

Answer (score 1):

[Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-7.0) method will replace the char if it's found e.g. `result = result.Replace("7", "1");`. If you still want to check whether the char is present then you use the [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-7.0) method. it will return -1 if the char is not found else will return the index of the first char it finds. you can add a check `if index > -1`

Comment: OP already uses both methods in the code.